# Find the thickness of the sealant line using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to find the sealant in the image and also find the area, length and thickness of the sealant.

[image: sealant on flywheel housing].

Comment: Stack Overflow requires you to make some effort yourself. Have you worked out how to scale distances off your image yet? Have you worked out how to separate the sealant yet? Please show your code so far.

Comment: I can extract the sealant from the image by doing the image processing steps like .... 1.convert it to gray  2.applying the filters to eliminate the noise like gaussian blur 3. Adaptive thresholding . After that i find the closed contours and then find the area of the contour as well as length using contourArea and minArclength. But i'm not able to find out the thickness.....

Answer (score 2):

In broad terms, one way to determine the mean thickness of a line is as follows.

**Separate**

First, separate the line from the background - probably using the Hue (in HSV) space in your case.

[image]

**Skeletonize**

Now use some sort of skeletonising or thinning or pruning to get a single pixel wide representation of the line.

[image]

**Ratio**

Now you have a 1-pixel wide line and also the (fatter) line you want to measure, so the average thickness of your lines is somewhere close to the ratio of the means of the two images.

Comment: Tq so much....Can you provide any source link to skeletonising the image..

Answer (score 2):

I didn’t want to answer the question but I don’t have enough reputation to put the proper name of the skeleton thinning. You want a non maximal suppression algorithm.

The rest can be done in open cv. Been a long time since I’ve needed to generate a skeleton but i’m fairly certain there’s a skeletonisation algorithm in open cv. (I’ve never been able to find their non max and always end up using my own!)

Good luck !